# Hadoop single node installation - formatting error - Content is not allowed in prolog

Tags: xml, hadoop

I'm trying to do a hadoop single node installation.

I am following [this](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/#sun-java-6) article for hadoop installation instructions. One of the steps I need to do is to format the hadoop file system using the command

**hduser@dbserver:~/hadoop/conf$ /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format**

```
hduser@dbserver:~/hadoop/conf$ /home/hduser/hadoop/bin/hadoop namenode -format
12/02/06 18:24:31 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG: 
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = dbserver/127.0.1.1
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 0.20.203.0
STARTUP_MSG:   build = http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-    0.20-security-203 -r 1099333; compiled by 'oom' on Wed May  4 07:57:50 PDT 2011
 ************************************************************/
 [Fatal Error] core-site.xml:6:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 12/02/06 18:24:31 FATAL conf.Configuration: error parsing conf file:  org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
 12/02/06 18:24:31 ERROR namenode.NameNode: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1237)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:1093)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:1037)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:438)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.setStartupOption(NameNode.java:1124)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1141)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1162)
 Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:249)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:180)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1142)
... 6 more

    12/02/06 18:24:31 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
    /************************************************************
      SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at dbserver/127.0.1.1
    ************************************************************/
```

i get the above error message when trying to format

Any suggestions to fix this issue are welcome :) .

the core-site.xml file is here for your reference @zensen

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

 <!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

  n: conf/core-site.xml -->
  <property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
  </property>

    <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
    <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
    scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
    uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
     the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
    determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
   </property><configuration>
```

~

Answer (score 5):

Well this isn't really a Hadoop problem.

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
```

Means that your XML file is incorrect. And to be more precise it contains some characters before `<?xml`. Are there any characters in `core-site.xml` at the very beginning before `<?xml`? If so then remove them. Remember that those might not show in all editors (depending on the encoding).

Comment: thanks Zenzen for your valuable hints. I use the VI editor in ubuntu terminal and I dont see any characters before <?xml?

Comment: The problem is solved. It was a formatting error in the core-site.xml file. please accept my thanks for this wonderful help.

Comment: No problem. Had hard time setting it up the first time, too :) For future notice: you can upvote answers you like and mark one as "accepted" (both options are next to each answer).

Answer (score 2):

**Error:**

```
[Fatal Error] core-site.xml:1:36: Element type "xml" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
16/09/05 13:59:48 FATAL conf.Configuration: error parsing conf core-site.xml
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 36; Element type "xml" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2539)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setBoolean(Configuration.java:1451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
16/09/05 13:59:48 ERROR namenode.NameNode: Failed to start namenode.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 36; Element type "xml" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2645)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2405)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1143)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1115)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setBoolean(Configuration.java:1451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:321)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:487)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1559)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/home/amtex/Documents/installed/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 36; Element type "xml" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:150)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2480)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.parse(Configuration.java:2468)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2539)
    ... 11 more
16/09/05 13:59:48 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
16/09/05 13:59:48 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
```

Check the xml syntax in core-site.xml

**Solution:**

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
to 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```